# complex hierarchical query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My data looks like this:

```
art_nr werbeart  leit  basis    
222    1           
333    2         222    
444    3               222
555    4         444   222
```

So I have 4 levels (werbeart column).

Level 2 always has leit = art_nr of level 1

Level 3 always has basis = art_nr of level 1

Level 4 always has leit = art_nr of level 3 and basis = art_nr of level 1.

As the column names are different between levels (leit / basis), how it is possible to do a hierarchical query to display the data starting from level 1, until level 4?

Is it possible to do this in Oracle?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the results you want.

Comment: The result is like above where I put the data. And there are more werbeart 1 with more childs, I want to display them in an ordered way. First parent with all his leafs, second parent , etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH werbeart = 1
CONNECT BY werbeart = PRIOR werbeart + 1
AND (  ( werbeart = 2 AND PRIOR art_nr = leit )
    OR ( werbeart = 3 AND PRIOR leit   = basis )
    OR ( werbeart = 4 AND PRIOR art_nr = leit AND PRIOR basis = basis )
    )
ORDER SIBLINGS BY art_nr;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( art_nr, werbeart, leit, basis ) AS
SELECT 222, 1, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL           
SELECT 333, 2, 222,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 444, 3, NULL, 222  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 555, 4, 444,  222  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 1, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL           
SELECT 234, 2, 123,  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 345, 3, NULL, 123  FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
SELECT 567, 3, NULL, 123  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 4, 345,  123  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 678, 4, 567,  123  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ART_NR | WERBEART | LEIT | BASIS
> -----: | -------: | ---: | ----:
>    123 |        1 | null |  null
>    234 |        2 |  123 |  null
>    345 |        3 | null |   123
>    456 |        4 |  345 |   123
>    567 |        3 | null |   123
>    678 |        4 |  567 |   123
>    222 |        1 | null |  null
>    333 |        2 |  222 |  null
>    444 |        3 | null |   222
>    555 |        4 |  444 |   222
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8cdb8ce5869d3e3c23bbfd9ba3c3d432)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why a hierarchical query is needed.  If you just need to assign the level, you can do something like this:

```
select t.*, 1 as level, art_nr as highest
from t
where leit is null and basis is null
union all
select t.*, 2 as level, leit
from t
where leit is not null and basis is null
union all
select t.*, 3 as level, basis
from t
where leit is null and basis is not null
union all
select t.*, 4 as level, basis
from t
where leit is not null and basis is not null;
```

Or more simply:

```
select t.*,
       (case when leit is null and basis is null then 1
             when leit is not null and basis is null then 2
             when leit is null and basis is not null then 3
             else 4
        end) as level,
       (case when leit is null and basis is null then art_nr
             when leit is not null and basis is null then level
             when leit is null and basis is not null then basis
             else basis
        end) as highest
from t
order by highest, level;
```

Comment: Because I want data to be ordered.. for example
1
2
2
3
4
1
2
3
3
4

etc

the parent can have many childs, and there are more parents (werbeart 1).
And werbeart is a database column

Comment: @Roger26 . . . Just add an `order by`.  I added it to the second query.